# Text missing when exporting .usdz file from Reality Composer

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

I made a simple label in Reality Composer which looks like this.

[image]

I export it as a .usdz file type with the standard export dialogue.

[image]

However, when viewing the model after export the text is missing. I can see it as a child in the model tree though. What am I missing?

[image]

Both sides of the 3D object were checked in the viewer.

Comment: Same problem with version 1.5 (190) Reality Composer. Have you managed to make it work in the meantime?